# Open Mobile menu drawer with custom button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, woocommerce, navigation-drawer

I added a sticky bottom menu which will be visible only on mobile devices.

[image]

Here is the complete code of the widget :

```
    <head>
          
        <style>
            /* Add some styling for the sticky section */
          .sticky-section {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #f8f8f8;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 99;
            display: flex;
            height: 70px;
            justify-content: space-around;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.11);
              }
          
          .sticky-section-nav {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #f8f8f8;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 999;
            display: flex;
            height: 70px;
            justify-content: space-around;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.11);
              }
        
            /* Hide the sticky section on desktop screens */
            @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
            .sticky-section {
            display: none;
            }
            }
            /* styling for the links */
            .sticky-section-bar-nav-grid a {
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin: 10px;
            font-size: 1.3rem;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            }
            /* add font awesome icons */
          .sticky-section .fa {
            font-size: 1.6rem;
            }

        .sticky-section-bar-nav-grid{
            align-items: center;
            border-right: 1px solid #eee;
            display: flex;
            flex: 1 0 auto;
            justify-content: center;
            padding: 0px 20px;
            position: relative;
        }
            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div class="sticky-section">
                    <ul class="sticky-section-nav" style="background-color: #fff; border-color: #000">
                       <li class="sticky-section-bar-nav-grid">
                          <a class="sticky-section-icon-1" href="/home">
                            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0732/1701/6089/files/home_1.png?v=1684754596" style="width: 20px;  ">
                                <span class="sticky-section-menu-title" style="display: block;color: #000;">Home</span>
                          </a>
                       </li>
                        <li class="sticky-section-bar-nav-grid">
                            <a class="sticky-section-icon-2" href="/collections/all">
                              <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0732/1701/6089/files/category.png?v=1684754597" style="width: 20px;  ">
                                 <span class="sticky-section-menu-title" style="display: block;color: #000;">Categories</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sticky-section-bar-nav-grid">
                             <a class="sticky-section-icon-3" href="/cart">
                               <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0732/1701/6089/files/shopping-cart.png?v=1684754596" style="width: 20px;  ">
                                  <span class="sticky-section-menu-title" style="display: block;color: #000;">Cart</span>
                             </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sticky-section-bar-nav-grid">
                               <a class="sticky-section-icon-4" href="/cart">
                                 <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0732/1701/6089/files/user.png?v=1684754597" style="width: 20px;  ">
                                    <span class="sticky-section-menu-title" style="display: block;color: #000;">Cart</span>
                               </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
      </div>
        
    </body>
```

I wanted to open the default mobile menu drawer(which opens when we click on the hamnburger icon), when clicked on the category icon.

Can anyone help? I'll really appreciate.

One dev added this script and it worked on one of my website, but its not working on the other website(Same theme, same code, same drawer classes)

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function () {
       $(document).on("click", ".ad-menu-icon-1", function (e) {
          e.preventDefault()
          $('.menu-drawer-container .header__icon--menu').click();
      });
   }, 1500);
</script>
```

Comment: Add the JS you tried in your question, even if it didn't work.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I tried this code : <script>
  setTimeout(function () {
       $(document).on("click", ".ad-menu-icon-1", function (e) {
          e.preventDefault()
          $('.menu-drawer-container .header__icon--menu').click();
      });
   }, 1500);
</script>

Comment: What is the identifier (selector `class` or `id`) for your hamburger item (to be clicked by javascript)?

Comment: I checked from event listner in browser it show "header__icon header__icon--menu header__icon--summary link focus-inset" this class under click event.

Comment: And there is not another **explicit** `class` or `id` in the parent tag? Maybe you could add in your question the HTML output for it (with the parent tag)... Did you tried my answer code?

Comment: Yeah I tried but it didn't work. I tried it on my wordpress websitem I also tried only the script in my shopify website. But It wasn't working.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Actually I want to thank you for always being there to help. I really appreciate your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following jQuery code snippet, replacing `#hamburger` with the correct selector `class` or `id` for your "hamburger item" to be triggered to open the menu drawer:

```php
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_footer_script_test_js', 10);
function wp_footer_script_test_js() {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('body').on("click", ".sticky-section-icon-2", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("click"); // Just for testing (after remove it)

            $('button#mobile-toggle').click();
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

It should work.

Comment: I notice you added console.log, and I checked browser console, should I get any value? Actually I am getting 3 click

Comment: Sure, https://woo.cdesksolutions.com/

Comment: Can you please, why its not working here? I know Its complete different website, i changed the classes accordingly but still not working.

Comment: https://cdesk.myshopify.com/

Comment: It's not working as the site doesn't use jQuery (jQuery  library is not loaded), so you need to use pure Javascript code.

Comment: This was added : <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>